# In Emacs, how to use align-regexp to align <- and = together

Tags: regex, emacs, haskell

I've tried, with M-x align-regexp:

```
<-|=
(<-|=)
\(<-|=\)
\\(<-|=\\)
```

And the ones with <- and = reversed. But none work?

Example code as follows:

```
  (flags, params, errs) <- parseArgs <$> getArgs
  let options = foldr id [] flags -- Apply functions to list
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try `\(<-\|=\)` -- you need the (backslashed) parentheses, **and** you need to backslash the `|`

Comment: Detailed documentation is (currently) here: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regular-Expressions.html

Answer (score 6):

You need to escape the `|`:

```
\(<-\|=\)
```